# Laravel Query builder with Join table as nested array

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have following code. the result i get is a single array. is there any way i can make it a nested array?

```
$contents = RecentView::where('recent_views.user_id', $loggedUser)
                        ->leftJoin('feed_posts','recent_views.post_id','=','feed_posts.id')
                        ->leftJoin('users','feed_posts.user_id','=','users.id')
                        ->paginate(12)->toArray();
```

and the result is:

```
[id] => 71
[user_id] => 71
[post_id] => 529
[site_id] => 103
[date_time] => 2020-11-05 00:00:00
[title] => Lorem Ipsum
[description] => Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem 
                 Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
[image] => PiZ0OCrH.jpg
[hit] => 609
[website_id] => 103
[created_at] => 2012-05-02T00:00:00.000000Z
[name] => Franko
[username] => franko
[email] => test@test.com
```

But the Result i need is like:

```
[recent_views]=>
        [id] => 71
        [user_id] => 71
        [post_id] => 529
        [site_id] => 103
        [date_time] => 2020-11-05 00:00:00
[post]=>
        [title] => Lorem Ipsum
        [description] => Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem 
                         Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
        [image] => PiZ0OCrH.jpg
        [hit] => 609
        [website_id] => 103
        [created_at] => 2012-05-02T00:00:00.000000Z
[user]=>
        [name] => Franko
        [username] => franko
        [email] => test@test.com
```

is there any way to do this in laravel query builder?

Comment: Don't use join directly, use the eloquent relationship methods. Define the relations in your model, than use `->with()` for example. Check the documentation for example.

Comment: can u tell me how i can convert this code:

```
$contents = RecentView::where('recent_views.user_id', $loggedUser)
                        ->leftJoin('feed_posts','recent_views.post_id','=','feed_posts.id')
                        ->leftJoin('users','feed_posts.user_id','=','users.id')
                        ->paginate(12)->toArray();
```
to eloquent?

Comment: First add the relation to your Recent view model: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many after that, modify your query like so: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: too confusing for a beginner. still try for it. thanks for ur time

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-relationships

Comment: oh thanks man. that will be of great help for sure